How to set a header Subject using codeigniter 4
I'm using CodeIgniter 4 to send email, using a simple function, like this:
$email = \Config\Services::email();

$email->setTo('valid.email@outlook.com');
$email->setSubject('Just a test');
$email->setMessage('Simple email test');
if ($email->send()) {
    print('sucess Sending email.');
    die();
} else {
    $data = $email->printDebugger(['headers']);
    print('Error: ');
    print('<br>');
    print_r($data);
    die();
}

Well, if a send an email to a any valid gmail it works well and the email is send to it with no issues. But, if I tried any valid Outlook email I'm not able to send one. The Email has been sent but the postmaster@outlook.com returned this:
Remote server returned '550 5.6.0 CAT.InvalidContent.Exception: ExchangeDataException, Decoding of header Subject failed+ADs
What do I need to do to send an email to Outlook.com like when I send to Gmail.com?
Thank you in advance.
Nan Medeiros
P.S. Actually the postmaster return is bigger:
Remote server returned

'550 5.6.0 CAT.InvalidContent.Exception: ExchangeDataException,
Decoding of header Subject failed+ADs- raw value:
+AD0-?CHARSET?Q?+AD0-41+AD0-73+AD0-73+AD0-75+AD0-6E+AD0-74+AD0-6F+AD0-20+AD0-64+AD0-65+AD0-20+AD0-74+AD0-65+AD0-73+AD0-74+AD0-65?+AD0-; cannot handle content of message with InternalId 51715701212792,
InternetMessageId 674c5f4b7f8d51.39038554@gmail.com.'

I've kept the code to a minimum to focus on the problem.
People, I add this code to my function and Everything works fine:
$email = \Config\Services::email();
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['mailPath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
$config['wordWrap'] = true;

Actually I believe this ($config['charset']  = 'utf-8';) is the one that is missing.

My suggestion would be to use mail-tester.com - great tool and free for a few goes. that will hopefully get you in the right direction.
